# Have a folder have many group based permissions

Tags: files, permissions, users, group, acl

On a multi-user system, lets say I have the following groups:

"writers"
"readers"
"reviewers"

In the folder /Documents

- writers should be able to write files, but not read others or even see other files that they themselves don't own through `ls`.
- readers should be able to see all documents in `ls` and read them all
- A reader should be able to give a user in the group reviewers r/w access to a particular file contained in /Documents

How would I go about implementing this? For the reader giving a particular use r/w access I figure this could be done through sudo config and giving users of that group ONE sudo command. But for the folder I do not know how I can have multiple group based permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide files in a directory with permissions - you need to create a sub directory the user (or group) does not have permission to access (if you have sufficient files that you need 3 groups of people to work them then putting all the files in the same directory seems a bit of a silly starting point).

If you expect to securely provide the ability for readers to grant access to particular files then you're going to have to write a fairly complicated bit of code.

OTOH if you stop trying to implement an entire workflow via permissions in a single directory, it becomes a lot simpler e.g. give each writer their own directory (drwxr-s--- which readers as the group owner). Provide another directory (or per-user directories) for the reviewers that the readers have write permissions on so they can make the files available to the reviewers.